# Autocomplete data fields in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am new in CakePHP. I have a CakePHP (2.5.1) application which has *streets* table (with columns id, street_name, house_no, district, city). I need to autocomplete a form by extracting the table data. It should be like, the user will be typing a street name in the *Street Name* field of a form which has fields- *Street Name*, *House No*, *District* and *City*. After selecting a street name from auto suggestions, corresponding data (*House No*, *District* and *City*) will be populated in the other fields.

Now, over 25000 data rows are loaded in the *streets* table which is the entire street database of a city. it is a ClearDB database on Windows Azure. *streets* table is not linked with other tables of the application through foreign keys. I have Street model, StreetsController , but view is in different folder (app/View/User/add.ctp ). *Street* model  in app/Model/Street.php is following:

```
  class Street extends AppModel {

    public function getStreetNames($term = null) {
      if(!empty($term)) {
        $streets = $this->find('list', array(
          'conditions' => array(
            'street_name LIKE' => trim($term) . '%'
          )
        ));
        return $streets;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

In app/Controller/StreetsController.php,

```
class StreetsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function autocomplete($term){

    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $data = $this->Street->getStreetNames($term);
        $this->set(compact('data'));
        $this->set('_serialize', array('data'));

        echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
  }
```

In app/webroot/js/View/Users/streetdata.js file,

```
  (function($) {
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: "/streetdata.json",
        minLength: 1
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The input forms are in different controller. In app/View/Users/streetdata.ctp file,

```
 <?php

      echo $this->Html->script('View/Users/streetdata', array('inline' => false));  

     ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Street', array(
            'class' => 'form-horizontal', 
            'role' => 'form',
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),

                'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                'class' => array('form-control'),
                'label' => array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'),
                'between' => '<div class="col-lg-3">',
                'style'=>array('width:200px; height:35px;'),
                'after' => '</div>',
                'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')),
        ))); ?>

        <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Street data '); ?></legend>

        <?php
               echo $this->Form->input('Street.street_name', array(
                            'class' => 'ui-autocomplete',
                            'id' => 'autocomplete'));

               echo $this->Form->input('Street.house_no');
               echo $this->Form->input('Street.district');
               echo $this->Form->input('Street.city');
    ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Proceed')); ?>
```

in View/Layouts/default.ctp, i have added followings

```
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');  
    echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => false));
    echo $this->Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', array('inline' => false));

    echo $this->Html->css('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->fetch('script');

    echo $this->Html->charset();
```

But the autocomplete fields (street name and others) are not working.

I found following error messages in the console of chrome browser :

```
-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:26949/Users/js/jquery.js 
-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:26949/Users/js/bootstrap.min.js 
-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined           bootstrap.min.js:6
```

I am struggling to find a solution. Could anyone tell me please what is wrong here ? is it because of the location of .js file ? am i missing anything here?

Comment: What's your opinion about `http://localhost:26949/Users/js/jquery.js` being called but not found?

Comment: @Álvaro González , should i put jquery.js (which is now in /app/webroot/js/ folder) in app/webroot/js/View/Users/ folder ? i am new in cakephp. please help me to find a way.

Comment: You're also loading jQuery a minimum of three times. If you can't get that right, it's no wonder that jQuery-based code doesn't work.